# Device Orientation and Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, device-orientation, ngcordova

I have a problem with Device Orientation, Ionic and Cordova/ngCordova
I've already run the command:
"cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device-orientation"
to install the device orientation plugin
It installed without problem.

Then I add the following code to my app:

```
    .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope,$cordovaDeviceOrientation) {
$cordovaDeviceOrientation.getCurrentHeading().then(function(result) {
       var magneticHeading = result.magneticHeading;
       var trueHeading = result.trueHeading;
       var accuracy = result.headingAccuracy;
       var timeStamp = result.timestamp;

$scope.values=magneticHeading+" "+trueHeading+" "+accuracy+" "+timeStamp;
    }, function(err) {
      // An error occurred
    });
    })
```

After executing cordova run android I got this error.
*Cannot read property 'getCurrentHeading' of undefined*.

I tested this code on the browser, Genymotion or Samsung Galaxy Tab 4, but always I got the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cordova plugins are to be used on a real device. Also theses plugins should be used on the DeviceReady function of cordova.

Answer (score 2):

There's two things you need to know:

First: This kind of plugin, like device orientation, need to be tested in real devices once it use a accelerometer hardware to work.

Second: You need to use the DeviceReady EventListner to use the plugins, so, you need to do something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
  $cordovaDeviceOrientation.getCurrentHeading().then(function(result) {
    var magneticHeading = result.magneticHeading;
    var trueHeading = result.trueHeading;
    var accuracy = result.headingAccuracy;
    var timeStamp = result.timestamp;

    $scope.values=magneticHeading+" "+trueHeading+" "+accuracy+" "+timeStamp;
    }, function(err) {
      // An error occurred
  });
}, false);
```

If you want, there's a seed for angularjs + cordova + angular-material here:
https://github.com/marioaleogolsat/cordova-angular-angularMaterial-seed

Answer (score 0):

Your device may not have a compass.